# Why is the conditional operator in java behaving diffrently with conversions? I want to print float as integer form if the decimal part is 0

Tags: java, casting, format, conditional-operator

I wanted to make a type of formatted printing (without using the printf() method) so that I can print a float varible without decimal point if the number does not contain a decimal part. I chose to make an inline if/else statement using the conditional operator. Debugging evaluates to true, however it still prints the decimal point. When used without the formated printing (for ex. a solution would be adding an if statement above instead of the conditional opperator) it prints it as expected. Why is this happening?

```
float rezultati = 15.0f;
System.out.println((rezultati % 1 == 0.0f ? ((int) rezultati) : rezultati));
System.out.println((int) rezultati);
```

outputs:

```
15.0
15
```

Casting doesnt seem to be the problem. I know I can work around it however I was wondering what is happening there?

```
System.out.println((rezultati % 1 == 0.0f ? 1 : rezultati));
```

output

```
1.0
```